# Java destroying object (clear all references)

Tags: java, reference, bukkit

I have the following problem. I have a list that contains beautiful POJOS. Example:

```
private ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList();

persons.add(new Person());
```

Now I want the following. I get an object out of the list and save it anywhere

```
private Person personOne = persons.get(0);
```

If I remove the person out of the list, I want all variables containing a reference to that removed object return null. So if I remove the object out of the main source I want to be cleared out of all variables and else containing it.

```java
persons.remove(0):
// At this point, I want `personOne` to be null.
```

In Minecraft, it is the same with the Bukkit Player: if I get a player `getServer().getPlayer()` and I save that player, if the player leaves the server, all references to them are null. How I can make that behaviour?

Comment: You basically can't without a lot of work.  The way to get an empty object is to use `new Person()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [WeakReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

```
private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

persons.add(new Person());

private WeakReference<Person> personOne = new WeakReference(persons.get(0));

Person pers = personOne.get();
if (pers != null) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It dont work
`
clans.add(new Clan(2));
System.out.println(clans.get(0));
WeakReference<Clan> weakClan = new WeakReference<Clan>(clans.get(0));
  
System.out.println(weakClan.get());
clans.clear();
System.out.println(weakClan.get());
`
It is still not null if i clear the src list. i want all variables containing that reference to be null